# Shape Intersection

Tags: java, shapes

I have shapes that use the Area class to represent its structure. I want to check whether a segement determined by two Points (start point and end point) intersects with Area. Such that segments start and end point are outside the Area (not considering partial line through the area).

The Area class has methods that check is Rectangle2D intersects the area but not a line
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html

Any suggestions or should I try a diffrent approach?

Answer (score 3):

Area has a simple method to do that:

```
java.awt.geom.Area.intersect(Area)
```

therefore, you can simply pass your segment to that method and verify if the result equals to the provided parameter.

Comment: that wouldnt help when the line is beyond the area ( start and end point of line is outside the area, but the line still intersects)

Comment: @Thatdude1 Then the returned Area won't be equal to the input area. Just make that check afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BasicStroke`. Pass the line and get stroked `Shape` (e.g. thickness=3) then just check the original `Area` and the stroked shape intersection.